# Quotient group of free product of groups

Tags: group-theory

I am trying to understand this theorem from Munkres:

If $G$ is the free product $G_1*G_2$, and $N_1$,$N_2$ are some normal subgroups of $G_1$ and $G_2$, respectively, and $N$ is the least normal subgroup of $G$ containing $N_1$ and $N_2$, then

$G/N \cong  (G_1/N_1)*(G_2/N_2)$

I cannot convince myself that $G \longrightarrow  (G_1*G2)/N \space$ will map $N_1$ to identity. 
Can anyone see why that holds ?

Comment: Because $N_1$ is contained in $N$ by definition.

Comment: Oh wow that is embarrassing. For some reason I kept trying to prove that it is mapping G to identity. Nevermind! Turns out just typing out stupid questions helps me think better.

Comment: Would be someone so kind to give me the exact reference for this theorem from Munkres (at least which book)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$N_1$ is contained in $N$, so since $G \to G/N$ maps $N$ to identity, it also sends $N_1$ to identity.